# Obtain Key Word from File Name in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I am working with R/RStudio.
I have a set of files with a repeating pattern.

```
"protein_class_Abcd.txt"
"protein_class_Egh.txt"
"protein_class_Bdc.txt"
```

I want to pull out the 'key word' {Abcd, Egh, Bdc} from the file name and use it later. The key word always come after "protein_class_" and is either 3 or 4 letters long then followed by .txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

```
gsub("^protein_class_([a-zA-Z]{3,4})\\.txt$","\\1",x)
```

Where x is your input vector of the 3 or more file names.

Here `\\1` referes to extracting the first capture group which is enclosed in the `()`. In this case it is `[a-zA-Z]{3,4}`. What this means is we want to match 3-4 letters `a-z` or `A-Z` between protein_class_ and .txt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
FileNames = c("protein_class_Abcd.txt",
"protein_class_Egh.txt",
"protein_class_Bdc.txt")

sub("protein_class_(.*)\\.txt", "\\1", FileNames)
[1] "Abcd" "Egh"  "Bdc"
```

Comment: It works! Great. @ G5W: Why did you put "\\1" in? What does that do?

Comment: Same as in @Sada93 's answer.  \\1 refers to the part in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You could do...

```
substr(x, 15, nchar(x)-4)
```

or programmatically

```
prefix  = "protein_class_"
postfix = ".txt"
substr(x, nchar(prefix)+1, nchar(x)-nchar(postfix))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a setup that allows for Perl expressions, you can use a positive look-behind `(?<=pattern)` to get text that comes after `"protein_class_"`. The `stringi` and `stringr` packages both do this by default, and have easy-to-use extract functions.

```r
files <- c("protein_class_Abcd.txt", "protein_class_Egh.txt", "protein_class_Bdc.txt")
stringr::str_extract(files, "(?<=protein_class_)[A-Za-z]{3,4}")
#> [1] "Abcd" "Egh"  "Bdc"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>